# how to install coreplot on mac and use it for ios applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I downloaded the latest coreplot installer from their site and extracted the package file  the procedure as mentioned in the installer was followed

1. Add to your project's .PCH file:

   #import < CorePlot/CorePlot.h >
2. Open Project -> Edit Project Settings and for All Configurations:

   ```
   3a. Add to Additional SDKS:
   ```

(System)
/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk

*I checked this but there is no sdk in the following path*

(User)${HOME}/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk

*I added this only to the additional sdks*

```
   3b. Add to Other Linker Flags:

   -ObjC -all_load -lCorePlot
```

4 Add the QuartzCore framework to the project.

**after this step i tried to run the application but a lot of errors are being displayed
the errors are** : 
**warning: "__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED" redefined
warning: this is the location of the previous definition
error: syntax error before '^' token
error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function**

how to correct this error?

1. Add a CPGraph to your application.**//how to add the CPGraph**

any detailed description on how to install this.urgently required

Comment: please don't use `urgently required` we are all here to help each other but with out urgency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that Simply without any complications please navigate to this link:

[Instructions for using Core Plot in your OS X or iPhone/iPod Touch application](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications)

Read the Wiki section carefully and Good luck.